# Chrome ver. 58 "TypeError: navigator.storage.estimate is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, navigator

I have a chunk of code that runs `navigator.storage.estimate()` for my indexedDB when the web app spins up on an Android tablet that should be running Android 7.1.1.

I am encountering an issue on Androids which uses the chrome browser ver. 58 and this occurs:

`TypeError: navigator.storage.estimate is not a function`

From the MDN documentation it seems that `.estimate()` should be supported since version 52.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/estimate

Browser versions beyond 58 also don't seem to encounter the same problem either.

Here's the code that runs the function:

```
const storageSetup = async () => {
    let errorMessage = undefined;

    try {
        const granted = await navigator.storage.persist();
        if (granted)
            console.log("Storage is now going to be persistent...", granted);
    } catch (error) {
        errorMessage = `Client did not allow storage to be persistent..${error}`;
    }

    try {
        const response = await navigator.storage.estimate();
        console.log("Storage Estimate, ", response, "Usage: ", (response.usage * 100 / response.quota).toFixed(2));
    } catch (error) {
        errorMessage = `estimate() is not supported on tablet, ${error}`;
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to start by being on the current, secure version of Chrome? We're on v80 at the moment. V58 is from April of 2017, no one except experts who locked their browser out of auto-updating would be using it anymore. Unless you're actually talking about the Android WebView browser, in which case you're going to have to explain which version of Android you're on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The android tablets are locked on Browser 58 and could not be updated due to a third party MDM that we do not have control over. I believe the android version is 7.1.1 but I have no control over whether the tablets were updated at this point. I updated the original post to include Android version.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation that you are using is for `StoreManager` not for `navigator.storage`.

```
  const storageSetup = async () => {
    let errorMessage = undefined;
    const storage = navigator.storage || StoreManager;
    try {
        const granted = await storage.persist();
        if (granted)
            console.log("Storage is now going to be persistent...", granted);
    } catch (error) {
        errorMessage = `Client did not allow storage to be persistent..${error}`;
    }

    try {
        const response = await navigator.storage.estimate();
        console.log("Storage Estimate, ", response, "Usage: ", (response.usage * 100 / response.quota).toFixed(2));
    } catch (error) {
        errorMessage = `estimate() is not supported on tablet, ${error}`;
    }
```

Comment: (edit) Sorry, I really thought it worked but apparently StorageManager is undefined on Browser 58 as well. You are , correct, that I misread the documentation though. If you have any pointers I'd gladly hear them, thanks

Comment: @fishcakesAndCoffee  is the persist is undefine or StoreManager? They were using requestPersistent instead of persist.

Comment: StorageManager itself is undefined, but so was navigator.storage.estimate. It seems like navigator.storage & navigator.storage.persist are defined though